# Can I run PIVPN with Wireguard without MASQUERADING?

Tags: raspberry-pi, vpn, nat, wireguard

When installing `pivpn` on Raspberry Pi it will create an iptables rule:

```
pi@RPi64:~ $ sudo iptables -L -t nat                                                                                                      
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)                                                                                                                                                                                                             
target     prot opt source               destination                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
target     prot opt source               destination                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
target     prot opt source               destination                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)                                                                                                                                                                                                            
target     prot opt source               destination                                                                                                                                                                                         
MASQUERADE  all  --  10.122.242.0/24      anywhere             /* wireguard-nat-rule */
```

I think it does this by inserting the rule via `iptables-persistant`:

```
pi@RPi64:~ $ cat /etc/iptables/rules.v4                                                                                                                                                                                                      
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Fri Aug 12 08:07:21 2022                                                                                                                                                                              
*nat                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.122.242.0/24 -o eth0 -m comment --comment wireguard-nat-rule -j MASQUERADE                                                                                                                                              
COMMIT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
# Completed on Fri Aug 12 08:07:21 2022
```

This is on the server side, of course. If I want to fully connect from a client to this server, I need to add masquerading on the client by inserting a similar rule on the client:

```
pi@schwarz:~ $ sudo iptables -L -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

I do it like this:

```
pi@schwarz:~ $ sudo cat /etc/wireguard/schwarz.conf                                                                         
[Interface]                                                                                                             
PrivateKey = 
Address = 10.122.242.4/24                                                                                                
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o schwarz -j MASQUERADE                                                        
PreDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o schwarz -j MASQUERADE                                                      
DNS = 9.9.9.9, 149.112.112.112                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
[Peer]                                                                                                                    
...
```

I then add static routes on both routers, so that traffic to the respective LAN is routed to the wireguard server or the client from other clients in those LANs.

This way I am able to fully connect to all devices in both LANs from any client in both LANs.

The problem with this approach is, that clients lose their original IP from the original LAN and will instead appear in the other network with the IP of the wireguard client (plus a port). This is of course due to NATing (masquerading).

Everything works fine this way.

Except one service: Logitechmediaserver. This server can not handle all clients that come from a remote LAN because they now have the same IP. To be more specific, the problem are only some Logitech clients (Radio). The clients connect fine on the server but they don't see the server responding. Other clients (Boom) connect fine. They use a different protocol.

This made me wonder why `pivpn` is even masquerading the IPs. Should it not suffice to have static routes from the LANs to the client/server and on those clients/server to the tunnels they create?

Why the masquerading? Is it done for the case of the Wireguard server acting also as a ISP router to the internet? This is not the case here. The router is always on a different machine.

**Long story short, I was wondering if it should be possible in general to remove the masquerading with `pivpn`.** Also, maybe someone can point to an error I have in my setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Masquerading in general is used for access to one network from a second network where the first network isn't set up to route replies back to the second. You apply masquerading to packets going out the gateway to the first network (rewriting the packets' source address to use the gateway's address), so that other hosts on that network will reply back to the gateway (which will translate the destination of reply packets back to the original source address).

You don't need masquerading if you are connecting two LANs, and each LAN is set up to route to the other through its own WireGuard gateway (the classic site-to-site WireGuard configuration).

You do need masquerading if you are connecting a LAN (or WireGuard network) to the Internet (ie *routing to* the Internet, not merely *tunneling through* the Internet).

With a site-to-site connection, if the LAN router on each LAN is also the WireGuard gateway, you usually would not use masquerading; usually you would just set up the WireGuard interface on each LAN router with a route (and appropriate `AllowedIPs` setting) to the other LAN, and add firewall rules to the routers that allow appropriate access from one site to the other.

In your case, where it sounds like you have a gateway (your Pis) at each site that is different than the LAN router, you can remove the need for masquerading by 1) adding the route to the other site to each LAN router (or alternatively to each individual device that needs to access the other site), and 2) adding the other site's LAN network to the `AllowedIPs` setting on the WireGuard gateway.

It sounds like you may have already done this; but to give a concrete example, if you are connecting two LANs, 10.100.100.0/24 and 10.200.200.0/24, and the WireGuard gateway in LAN 1 is 10.100.100.123 and the WireGuard gateway in LAN 2 is 10.200.200.234, you would add a route to the LAN router (or individual devices) in LAN 1 like the following (using the appropriate LAN-connected interface for the router or device, like eth1):

```
10.200.200.0/24 via 10.100.100.123 dev eth1
```

And a corresponding route to the LAN router (or individual devices) in LAN 2 like the following:

```
10.100.100.0/24 via 10.200.200.234 dev eth1
```

In the WireGuard config for LAN 1, you'd include the other site's network in the `AllowedIPs` setting for the other site:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.122.242.1/24
...

[Peer]
AllowedIPs = 10.122.242.2, 10.200.200.0/24
...
```

And correspondingly, in the WireGuard config for LAN 2, you'd include LAN 1's network in the `AllowedIPs` setting for LAN 1:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.122.242.2/24
...

[Peer]
AllowedIPs = 10.122.242.1, 10.100.100.0/24
...
```

With that configuration in place, you can safely remove the masquerading rules from your WireGuard gateways, and traffic can be routed from one site to the other and back without any NAT.

If you still wanted to use one of the WireGuard gateways as a gateway to the Internet, however, you could keep the masquerading rule, but simply carve out an exception for packets destined for the gateway's own LAN; for example, like this on the WireGuard gateway for LAN 2:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING ! -d 10.200.200.0/24 -o eth0 -J MASQUERADE
```

One minor, unrelated nit about the WireGuard config you posted: you almost never want to include the `DNS` setting in a site-to-site configuration. You'd usually only use the `DNS` setting on the "point" side of a point-to-site configuration, for the purpose of using a different DNS resolver on the endpoint when its WireGuard interface is up than when it is down.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my thoughts so I had the endurance to try it. Also, you pointed out a small error in my config: I was missing the server's tunnel end point in the client's config.